# Override imported module's component declaration

Tags: angular

Can you override a third-party module's component declaration?

Say you're using a third-party module that declares and exports two components:

```
@NgModule({
  exports: [Cmp1, Cmp2]
  declarations: [Cmp1, Cmp2]
})
export class ThirdPartyModule {}
```

`Cmp1`'s template:

```
`<app-cmp2></app-cmp2>`
```

`Cmp2`'s template:

```
`<p>foo</p>`
```

`AppModule` imports `ThirdPartyModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [ThirdPartyModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`AppComponent`'s template is just `<app-cmp1></app-cmp1>`.

How would you redeclare/override the third-party module's implementation of `Cmp2` so that not `Cmp2` but `MyCmp2` is rendered inside `Cmp1`?

Obviously I'd need to extend Cmp2 (or implement its interface):

```
@Component({
  ... // same selector as Cmp2
})
export const MyCmp2 extends Cmp2 {}
```

I tried providing it via DI: `{ provide: Cmp2, useClass: MyCmp2 }` which didn't work.

Simply declaring it in the app module won't work either, because angular throws when two components match the same selector. Is this even possible?

My specific usecase is overriding the header component of material's horizontal stepper.

Comment: Hi, i'm currently in the same issue than you, if you found an answer or a workaround. please could you point me in the right direction? this is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57955904/its-possible-overwrite-mat-monthly-view-component-on-mat-datepicker-to-add-week

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not

Comment: ok thanks, this is a tough one

Comment: Hi @j2L4e , I'm facing the exact same situation. Just wanted to check if you found any solution since ErnestoAlfonso's comment

Comment: We didn't try any further, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do it the way you describe, since you'll either be declaring two components with the same name, or no components at all.

One possible solution is to use [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#resolving-components) with a configuration service.

Lets say you want to use `ComposableComponent` with a different `InnerComponent` (either `InnerComponent1` or `InnerComponent2`) on two different modules `ComposedWithInner1Module` and `ComposedWithInner2Module`.

`ComposedWithInner1Module` is defined as:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ComposableComponentModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Config,
      useValue: { component: InnerComponent1 }
    }
  ],
})
export class ComposedWithInner1Module {}
```

`ComposedWithInner2Module` is defined as:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ComposableComponentModule],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: Config,
      useValue: { component: InnerComponent2 }
    }
  ],
})
export class ComposedWithInner2Module {}
```

On `ComposableComponentModule` you need to say that both `InnerComponent2` or `InnerComponent1` can be injected dynamically, which is done through the `entryComponents` property:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ComposableComponent],
  exports: [ComposableComponent]
  entryComponents: [InnerComponent2, InnerComponent1]

})
export class ComposableComponentModule {}
```

Then `ComposableComponent` gets the injected `InnerComponentX` through the injected `Config` and loads it into the template with `ComponentFactoryResolver`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'prl-column-header-extras',
  template: '<p> I'll be substituted by InnerComponent2 or InnerComponent1 </p>'
})
export class ComposableComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private config: Config,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const comp = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(
      this.config.component
    );

    this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    const ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(comp);

    ref.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
  }
}
```

Comment: This approach requires `ComposableComponent` to be designed for composability. It doesn't enable you to inject a child component into an arbitrary parent.

Comment: yes, you're right. I don't think it is possible to "duck type" components through ngModule. Angular likes its boilerplate.

Answer (score -1):

In your case it is not possible. For such things ng-content is used.
You can read about it here https://angular.io/guide/content-projection